# WebStorm Intellisense/Code Completion Just Not Working

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm struggling to get WebStorm Code Completion working and haven't been able to figure it out. I've been all over the forums and have tried everything suggested and would love some help.

After struggling for several hours, I decided to open up a fresh project in hopes of isolating the issue. Surprisingly, I couldn't even get *that* to work. I fired up a *brand new*, empty Node folder and added a *index.js* with the following code:

```
var ReadableStream = require('stream').Readable;
var pr  = require('process');
let Joi = require('joi');

var rs = new ReadableStream();

Joi.object().keys ({

count: Joi.number().integer().required().description('')
})
```

I am NOT getting code completion for either the **Joi** object, the **pr** object, or the **rs** object. Note that I **AM** getting code completion properly in **Visual Studio Code**.

Here's what I've done already:

- I made sure to run  `npm install joi`, `npm install process`, and `npm install stream` and verified their presence in `package.json`...
- I've made sure that the Node core package is enabled in File | Settings |Langauges & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM

I'm running WebStorm 2018.2.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 4):

Put cursor on `'joi'` in `require('joi')`, hit `Alt+Enter`, choose to install Typescript definitions for better completion:

[image]

Do the same for `process`.
This should do the thing:

[image]

And this is just what VSCode actually does